# How to trigger an action when clicking a disabled JMenuItem?

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, jmenuitem, disabled-control

I did a bit of googling and poking around in SO but all examples are find are for cases when the `JMenuItem` is enabled.

Context for what I'm trying to do is that I want my disabled `JMenuItem` (because of limited privileges), when clicked, to display a pop up box requesting that the user upgrade so that they can access said `JMenuItem`.

The following is a stripped down version of what I currently have, nothing got printed out on the command line:

```
public class ExportMenuItem extends JMenuItem
{
    public ExportMenuItem()
    {
        super("Menu Item Name");

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
            {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
                {
                    if (!isEnabled())
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(editor.getFrame(), "Hello world.");
                        System.out.println("Sys print hello.");
                    }
                    System.out.println("Sys print hello outside.");
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does a tool-tip appear for a disabled menu item?  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: I created a JMenuItem, made it disabled and then added a MouseListener to it. The code worked fine for me.

Comment: `// And the remaining methods to implement...`  Use a `MouseAdapter` instead.

Comment: I also created a `JMenuItem` and it responds the same to a mouse click even if it is disabled.

Comment: You should create a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that shows that it does not work. Otherwise, it's just guesswork in determining the issue as camickr and I have both verified on our end that it seems to work as expected.

Comment: @AndrewThompson No there's no tool-tip. But not surprising because it wasn't set up.

Comment: @CanadianDavid Trying to create a SSCCE/MCVE now. From what you and camickr said it seems like the issue might be the fact that something somewhere in my system is messing with things. Oh boy this is going to be fun. :(

Answer (score 2):

is this what you are looking for?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ExportMenuItem extends JMenuItem{

    public ExportMenuItem(){
        super("menu item");

        addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent){
                    if (!isEnabled())                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Upgrade me!");
                    }//end of if
                }//end of mouseClicked
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent mouseEvent){}
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent mouseEvent){}
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mouseEvent){}
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent){}

                // And the remaining methods to implement...
            });//end of anonymous class
    }//end of constructor

    public static void main(String[] a){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("menu");
        JMenuBar menuBar  = new JMenuBar();
        f.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setVisible(true);
        menuBar.add(menu);
        JMenuItem item = new ExportMenuItem();
        menu.add(item);
        item.setEnabled(false);
    }//end of main
}//end of class
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a complete different approach, that is more logical for users:

Place a describing text behind the menu item:

```
private void addRestartHint(JMenuItem m, String text) {
    final String spaceholder = "                                        ";
    String t = m.getText() + spaceholder;
    m.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    m.setText(t);
    m.add(new JLabel(text), BorderLayout.EAST);
}
```